# year date month in django template

Tags: python, django

I have a home page http://127.0.0.1:8000/home/ which presents a list of blogposts which are a snippet of each blogpost and each snippet links to the full blogpost page which has url for example http://127.0.0.1:8000/home/blog/2017/10/14/. the template for the full blogpost url with year month and day is working correctly however I get a NoReverseMatch on the homepage :

**Reverse for 'view_blogpost_with_pk' with keyword arguments '{'year': 2017, 'month': 10, 'day': 1}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['home/blog/(?P[0-9]{4})/(?P[0-9]{2})/(?P[0-9]{2})/$']**

I dont know why its using 2017/10/01 instead of the correct year month day. I think im missing something from the view

Here is my template for the home page:

```
<div class = "container">
<div class = "col-md-10">
    <div class ="well">
    {% for p in allposts %}
        <a href="{% url 'home:view_blogpost_with_pk' year=p.date.year month=p.date.month day=p.date.day %}"><img src="{{MEDIA_URL}}/{{p.pic}}"></a>
        <h1 class="text-uppercase"><a href="{% url 'home:view_blogpost_with_pk'  year=p.date.year month=p.date.month day=p.date.day %}">
            {{p.title}}</a></h1>
        <h3 id ="smallicons">
        <i id ="user" class="fa fa-user" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        <a href="{% url 'accounts:view_profile_with_pk' pk=p.author.pk %}">
        {{p.author.username}}</a>
        <i id = "clock" class="fa fa-clock-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>{{p.date}}
        <i id = "comments" class="fa fa-comment" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        <a href= "{% url 'home:view_blogpost_with_pk' year=p.date.year month=p.date.month day=p.date.day %}">
        {{p.comment_set.count}} comments</a> </h3>
        <p>{{p.body|truncatewords:"50"}}<a id= "readmore" href="{% url 'home:view_blogpost_with_pk' year=p.date.year month=p.date.month day=p.date.day %}"> read more</a></p>
        <hr id = "horizontalrule">
        <br>
    {%endfor%}
    </div>
```

URL For homepage:

```
url(r'^$', HomeView.as_view(), name = 'home'),
```

Home View:

```
class HomeView(TemplateView):

    template_name = 'home/home.html'

    def get(self,request):

        all_posts = BlogPost.objects.all().order_by('-date')
        args = {'allposts' : all_posts}
        return render(request, self.template_name, args)
```

---

URL for each blogpost:

```
url(r'^blog/(?P<year>[0-9]{4})/(?P<month>[0-9]{2})/(?P<day>[0-9]{2})/$', BlogPostView.as_view(),name = 'view_blogpost_with_pk')
```

View for each blogpost:

```
class BlogPostView(TemplateView):
template_name = 'home/blog.html'

def get(self,request,year,month,day):
    blogpost = BlogPost.objects.get(date__year=year, date__month=month, date__day=day)
    form = BlogPostForm()
    comments = Comment.objects.filter(comment_body_id=blogpost).order_by('-date')
    c = comments.count()


    args = {'bpost': blogpost,'form':form,'comments':comments,'c':c}
    return render(request,self.template_name, args)
```

Been scratching my head for a couple days now did not manage to find a solution yet any help much appreciated.

Comment: So are the dates shown here wrong?

Comment: Your `day` argument must be exactly 2 digits because of `{2}`. You are currently passing one digit (`day=1`). Try changing your regex to `{1,2}`

Comment: It is also a bad idea to use the blog date as a unique identifier. What happens if you publish multiple posts on the same day?

Comment: @Selcuk that's just brilliant it worked thank you so much! :) Yes I know searching by pk is faster than slug right? I am going to include a slug and pk but read that searching by pk is fastest, cheers again

Comment: I wouldn't worry about performance unless your site will be visited by millions of people.